# FullCalendar Time Line View

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I am using Full Calendar with Time Grid plugin, all is working good. I want to change color for past date & time. By dayRender event I could change color of previous date but not time, as for example view for week starting from Sunday 8 Spetember 2019 till 14 Saturday 2019. and open page on 10 Sep 2019 at 9.00 AM, I should change color until 10 Sep 2019 at 9.00 AM but I could do it until 9 Sep 2019.

How can I include time. My code pen
https://codepen.io/milindsaraswala/pen/VwZXpRM

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'resourceTimeGrid' ],
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridFourDay',
    soltDuration: '00:30:00',
    slotLabelInterval: '00:30:00',
    minTime:'07:00:00',
    maxTime:'24:00:00',
    slotLabelFormat:{
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: '2-digit',
      omitZeroMinute: false,
      meridiem: 'short'
    },
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimeGridDay,resourceTimeGridFourDay'
    },
    views: {
      resourceTimeGridFourDay: {
        type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
        duration: { weeks:1},
        buttonText: '7 days'
      }
    },
    resources: [
       { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
    ],
    //events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources=2',
    events:events,
    dayRender:function(day){

      if (moment(day.date).isBefore(moment())) {
          day.el.classList.add('disabledDates');
        }
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the previous days must more robustly by using a [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) without an end date:

```
validRange: function(nowDate) {
  return {
    start: nowDate
  };
},
```

As well as just visually greying out the dates this will also stop events being added or dragged onto them.

Greying out the *times* of the current day is much more problematic. That's because there is no single HTML element representing a "time slot" on a particular day which you can target in order to do an hour-by-hour or even minute-by-minute restriction. I think the best thing you can do here is to create a [background event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) which covers the period of the day up until the current time:

```
dayRender: function(day) {
  var d = moment(day.date).startOf("day");
  var today = moment().startOf("day");

  if (d.isSame(today)) {
    var now = moment();
    var evt = {
      start: today.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
      end: now.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
      rendering: "background",
      className: "disabledDates"
    }
    calendar.addEvent(evt);
  }
}
```

If you then wanted to restrict the creation / dragging of other events over the background event you can do via some of the [date selection settings](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting).

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/pozLWjo